# Software to live-stream presentations

Tags: presentation, online-learning

I would like to be able to live-stream presentations online in case my school closes. My presentations are in power point. Ideally I would like to share my screen so I can use other software simultaneously. Finally I would like student to be able to ask questions from home and be heard by everyone, but I would like to have control over who is heard.

Any software recommendations? Even better if it's open source, or at least free

Comment: Have you checked to see if your university has a solution already?  Both institutions I have been affiliated with had something that integrates with their management system (Blackboard, Canvas).

Comment: It's not a university, it's a high school. And they don't have anything in place at the moment (actually, I think I may have to be in charge of that)

Comment: Does your institution use Google Apps for Education to provide gmail and google drive to students?  If so, they've got access to Google Hangouts.

Comment: [Meta discussion pertaining to this question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4675/7734). You may also be interested in [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53774017#53774017).

Comment: More resources [here](https://www.ctl.upenn.edu/resources-and-strategies-teaching-remotely)

Comment: I reopened [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145280/7734) for now making it the current master question on this topic. If you can explain why your question is crucially different, please [edit] it to do so (and flag it to nominate for reopening). However, please note that high-school education is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

At my university we use [Zoom.](https://zoom.us/)

It allows you to host a room, share screens, create "breakout rooms" for group work, etc. Don't know what the limitations are as far as how much the free version gets you, but it would be worth poking around with.

Answer (score 1):

A free alternative to zoom is [Google Hangouts](https://hangouts.google.com), which works without installing any separate software for either side (neither you nor your students). Performance might be best with Google Chrome, but other browsers should work, too.

Comment: I have only used hangouts for one-on-one conversations. Is there a limit on how many people can join? Is it possible to set an "admin" role that will allow me to mute and unmute students?