# Alternatives to big-name proprietary remote-lecturing tools

Tags: tools, lecture-teaching-method, audio-video-recording, video-conference

As in many other universities, due to the coronavirus outbreak now we are supposed to do our teaching online in videoconference style. Our university suggests using either Microsoft Teams or Google Meet, but I am not so keen on using a service run by one of these data-collecting behemoths where "you are the product".

**Which alternatives exist to these two big players for videoconferencing with a large number of students?**

For my lectures, I would like to share my desktop's content (livestream) and my voice on microphone. Students should hopefully also have a way to give feedback and ask questions. You may assume ca. 100-200 students.

My university used to have an internal videoconferencing service but they discontinued it.

I would prefer something open source, in theory: I understand that bandwidth does not grow on trees, but that seems like a problem that could be solved using p2p, at least in theory. Otherwise, I am open to considering other commercial services that are a bit more privacy-preserving; for instance, something run by a company less focused on advertising and monetizing user data. Apple looks slightly better, and so does Amazon (Twitch -- it has ads, but I don't know how intrusive they are).

In the past I used to publish my in-class lecture videos, but I realize that by doing so without a class I would lose all interactivity.

Comment: We are using [Big Blue Button](https://bigbluebutton.org/) integrated into our university's LMS. However, for the recording, to avoid overloading the university servers, I'm using [OBS studio](https://obsproject.com/download).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano That looks like something that needs to be hosted by your university's server; unfortunately they refuse to do it (they discontinued their internal web-conferencing software).

Comment: One can use Zoom to record and host video, but for sizes that large you will likely need a Zoom Pro account. https://zoom.us/

Comment: We are using [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) for our journal club, not sure how well it would scale to 100+ participants though.

Comment: If you don't know about it yet, have a look also here, maybe you can find some possibility: https://solidarietadigitale.agid.gov.it/#/

Comment: [Meta discussion pertaining to this question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4675/7734). I also [scouted a potential suitability for Software Recommendations SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53774017#53774017).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Thanks, I did not know about that site. It includes a web conferencing service by Cisco, which looks more acceptable to me (at least Cisco makes money selling routers, not data). I have contacted them, even if their offer is targeted at industry only.

Comment: Reopening this question for now, as this is [the current meta consensus](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4675/7734) and this has a high immediacy.

Comment: Are you trying to do live two-way communication (you can stop mid-lecture and have a back-and-forth with students)?  Or are you looking to record a lecture which students watch later, and then you handle questions 1-on-1 afterwards?

Comment: @bta Live communication. Mostly one-way, but with the possiblity to ask questions (see the 3rd paragraph).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BigBlueButton](https://bigbluebutton.org/) is software designed for remote teaching. It makes it possible to teach using videos, share slides, annotate them, do breakout rooms, etc., and can be integrated with Moodle. It is open-source and can be self-hosted.

It is apparently not easy to set up, but can be done, and can scale to dozens of participants provided they don't all have their webcam set up (e.g., only the instructor and a few people asking questions share the webcam).

Answer (score 3):

A few resources exist to pick your free/libre and open source software:

- [FSFE](https://wiki.fsfe.org/action/edit/Activities/FreeSoftware4RemoteWorking)
- [FSF](https://libreplanet.org/wiki/Remote_Communication)
- [SFC](https://sfconservancy.org/blog/2020/mar/17/remotetools/)

Others have resources on how bad the proprietary software is:

- [EFF](https://www.eff.org/issues/covid-19)
- [EPIC](https://epic.org/privacy/ftc/zoom/)
- [NOYB](https://noyb.eu/en/interrupted-transmission)

In France there are more options:

- [Chapril](https://www.chapril.org/-services-.html)
- [Continuité Pédagogique](https://www.continuitepedagogique.org/)
- [Framasoft](https://framablog.org/2020/04/04/pour-un-plan-national-pour-la-culture-ouverte-leducation-ouverte-et-la-sante-ouverte/)
- [Service de webconférence pour l’éducation Nationale](https://educnat-ensemble.scaleway.com/)

In Italy there's some self-organisation:

- [iorestoacasa.work](https://iorestoacasa.work/)
- [Italian Wikibooks](https://it.wikibooks.org/wiki/Software_libero_a_scuola/Solidariet%C3%A0_digitale)

Some free software like Jitsi is extremely easy to set up but also very generous in its default configuration (allowing a number of participants or video quality which Google and Microsoft don't dream of allowing), so it's easy to go beyond its limits and end up dissatisfied.

When you need 100-200 simultaneous users, it's better to use a commercial provider with some experience handling such traffic. They can advise on how to configure your free software of choice so that it satisfies your needs without melting. You can usually find a list of the more established providers on the official website of the software project.